# How to print all results of Beautiful Soup at once?

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a list of twitter usernames. I need to get their number of followers. I used BS and requests. However, I've only received one account every time.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
purcsv = pd.read_csv('pureeng.csv', engine= 'python')
followers = purcsv['username']
followers.head(10)

handle = purcsv['username'][0:40]
temp = ("https://twitter.com/"+handle)
temp = temp.tolist() 

for url in temp:
    page = requests.get(url)

bs = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')

follow_box = bs.find('li',{'class':'ProfileNav-item ProfileNav-item--followers'})
followers = follow_box.find('a').find('span',{'class':'ProfileNav-value'})
print("Number of followers: {} ".format(followers.get('data-count')))
```

Comment: What is the result of ```print(len(temp))```?

Comment: 40 is the result, Eric.

Comment: We're likely going to need a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are looping over the urls first and fetching the content for each in the same variable `page` here:

```
for url in temp:
    page = requests.get(url)
```

so page will always contain the last url page accessed, to solve this you need to process a page once fetched

```
followers_list = []
for url in temp:
    page = requests.get(url)

    bs = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    follow_box = bs.find('li',{'class':'ProfileNav-item ProfileNav-item--followers'})
    followers = follow_box.find('a').find('span',{'class':'ProfileNav-value'})
    print("Number of followers: {} ".format(followers.get('data-count')))
    followers_list.append(followers.get('data-count'))
print(followers_list)
```

here is a full example to verify

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
purcsv = pd.read_csv('pureeng.csv')

followers = purcsv['username']

handles = purcsv['username'][0:40].tolist()

followers_list = []
for handle in handles:
    url = "https://twitter.com/" + handle
    try:
        page = requests.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to fetch page for url {url} due to: {e}")
        continue

    bs = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

    follow_box = bs.find('li',{'class':'ProfileNav-item ProfileNav-item--followers'})
    followers = follow_box.find('a').find('span',{'class':'ProfileNav-value'})
    print("Number of followers: {} ".format(followers.get('data-count')))
    followers_list.append(followers.get('data-count'))
print(followers_list)
```

output:

```
Number of followers: 13714085 
Number of followers: 4706511 
['13714085', '4706511']
```

You may consider using `async` function for fetching and processing those urls if you have two many of them.

Comment: Thanks! But, with this, I can only get one (unless I type all the usernames like what you did. My list is quite long

Comment: if you have them in a csv file, they will loaded in a list as you have above and processed one by one , eventually you will have all of them in ```followers_list```

Comment: I assumed the part where you fetch your data from the csv file works perfectly as I have no access to this file so I wrote two  random accounts just to check. if there is a problem in the first part reading data from the csv, then we will need a sample from that file to work with

Comment: I am getting this error: InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '0

Comment: I think not all of your urls are formed correctly, this may indicate that some of them are missing the schema/protocol -https/http-, which make request to fetch the page for this url fails or maybe the handles contain characters not valid for urls like endline

Comment: Could you include in your Question a sample of this csv, at least enough entries that make the script fail, so  I could better help you with that ?

Comment: I uploaded a pic instead. I can't upload a csv here.

Comment: Yes, I know but you can add it as ```csv text```, you can get the csv text by opening the file with a text editor. I could use the names from the screenshot, but I think the problem maybe of some hidden characters that is stored in your csv so I won't be able to detect that.

Comment: I really want to help you investigate that problem, but I cannot do that unless I have a sample to work with.

Comment: The site won't allow me post it. It gives an error. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: aha sorry for that. if you want, you could add a link -drive upload- for it here and I will attach it to your post.

Comment: done, check answer updated. converting the column to list removing the indexing

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH :))))) Saved me hours of tears

Comment: @jeannie you are welcome, if you are satisfied with that answer, mark it as accepted-little checkmark under the voting icons for this answer-, so this question will be known to be closed .